# gmap3 API - geoLatlng not giving exact location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, jquery-gmap3

I'm using gmap3's geolocation service to get a user's location and give them directions to a predefined destination.

the destination is (co-ordinates commented after):

```
var dest = "Unit 20, Tallaght Business Centre, Whitestown Road, Tallaght Business Park, Ireland";//53.282882, -6.383155
```

the user's location is sought using the following (i'm doing all the development for this in my office, which is the exact same address as `dest`):

```
//get user's location
        function getLocation(){
            $('#map').gmap3(
            { action : 'geoLatLng',
              callback : function(latLng){
                if (latLng){
                  plotRoute(latLng, dest);
                  alert(latLng); //this alerts (53.34410399999999, -6.267493000000059), should be my exact location which is the same as 'dest'
                  return;
                } else {
                  alert("Unable to determine your location. Enable geolocation services and try again, or consult the map for our location.");
                  $('#directions-panel').text("We were unable to give you directions. Please enable geolocation services on your device to see directions from your location to our office.");
                  plotMarker(dest);
                }
              }
            });
          }
```

so in theory what's alerted by `alert(Latlng);` should be the exact same as `dest`, no?

is this purely because of gmap3's limitations in pinpointing a user's location, or am I doing something incorrect? would I be better off using Google Maps JavaScript API v3?

full script can be seen here:
http://pastebin.com/Vz1syjvE

all help appreciated.

Comment: This is not Google Maps API V3 syntax so you're gonna have to find someone who knows the specific plugin you're using. Try to see if whoever wrote it has a support forum, somewhere. IMHO, plugins are counterproductive because they have more problems and less support than using the API directly.

Comment: Okay, I have posted on their forum before but with no replies, so support doesn't seem to be the best. I think I'm just going to start from scratch with Google Maps API V3. You don't happen to know of any tutorials/examples that relate to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: No, I don't, sorry. As I mentioned in my previous comment, I think plugins are a bad idea, therefore I never use any and I don't look for their tutorials or examples. The Google Maps API itself is well documented and well supported, so I always use it directly.

Comment: I meant tutorials/examples using Google Maps API V3. I've found them anyway, thanks for the help.